# Can I index a model field from another source file?

Tags: django

I have some tables that were installed as part of an outside library that have fields that need be indexed for speed purposes.  I can index them via the database command line, but I would prefer to tell django to do the indexing itself, but I don't want to have to patch and maintain the library.  Is there an easy way to tell Django in a source file outside of those models to index that field?

Comment: Are the source tables on the same database?

Answer (score 0):

I use south to manage my models and their respective data tables. I think this would be my approach, assuming the tables are all on the same database. (If they aren't, there is no genuine solution, and its probably not even worth looking to find some hacked-up way around this limitation to Django.)

```
$ python manage.py startapp data_models
$ python manage.py inspectdb > inspectdb.py
```

These two step creates a file with models to represent every table in the database. Copy the models for the data tables you want to work with from `inspectdb.py` into `data_models\models.py` file. Tweak the copied models as you would like. Then assuming you have south:

```
$ python manage.py convert_to_south data_models
$ python manage.py migrate data_models
```

Now you have an active model inside your django project for these data tables. Finally, set up the ForeignKey relationships you want to have if you haven't done so yet. Do the usual south updating dance if you changed any of your models:

```
$ python manage.py schemamigration [app-with-changed-models] --auto
$ [repeat above as necessary]
$ python manage.py migrate
```